# Setting output path to PostgreSQL in processing function of PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-3

I am studying PyQGIS to analyze gis data.
I want to set output path to PostgreSQL in QGIS 3.8 but I have no idea...

According to `processing.algorithmHelp('qgis:simplifygeometries')`,
only show `OUTPUT: ex> 'postgres:...'`

it is my code

```py
mycrs=QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
uri=QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost","5432","TSDLINK","postgres","password")
geometrycol="geom"
tb_1="tsd_level"
uri.setDataSource("public",tb_1,geometrycol)
layer_6=QgsVectorLayer(uri .uri(False),tb_1,"postgres")
layer_6.setCrs(mycrs,True)
mycontext=QgsProcessingContext()
param_simply={'INPUT':layer_6 ,"METHOD": 0,'TOLERANCE': 3000,'OUTPUT':'??????'}
processing.run('qgis:simplifygeometries',param_simply,feedback=None,context=mycontext)
```

**'output':?????????**

How to set path?

Answer (score 3):

To save the result in a postgres table you must create the connection string.

For example:

```
str_output_db = "postgis:dbname=\'" + self.dbname + "\' host=" + self.host + " port=" + self.port + " user=" + self.user + " password=" + self.password + " table=\"public\".\"" + table_name + "\" (the_geom) sql="
processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT': vlayer, 'OUTPUT': str_output_db})
```

Where vlayer is your vector layer and obviously you have to put your connection data, host, port etc.